# What does << do when used to assign an argument in a Ruby method?

Tags: ruby, function, recursion, argument-passing, tail-recursion

I came across this excellent piece of code over at http://projecteuler.net/ but I'm having trouble wrapping my mind around a certain part of it.

```
def generate(n, factors=[])
  return factors if n == 1
  new_factor = (2..n).find {|f| n % f == 0}
  generate(n / new_factor, factors << [new_factor])
end

factors = []
generate(4356463234, factors)
```

**Question**: When the generate function calls upon itself in line 4, what does **factors << [new_factor]** do?

Thank you for your insight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appends `[new_factor]` to the end of the `factors` array.

Comment: Thank you Finbarr for your fast answer! That's it! Just researched more into it.

Answer (score 0):

`factors` is an array, apparently of arrays.  `factors << [new_factor]` appends `[new_factor]` (a newly created one element array containing `new_factor`) to the end of `factors` and returns `factors`.  This results in `factors` being passed as the second argument to `generate`.

Comment: Indeed. Thank you very much for your answer Retief. :)